# Finding full SVD from reduced SVD

Tags: inverse, least-squares, svd

I am no math expert, so please forgive me for a lack of proper terminology, I will do my best:

I am trying to create an algorithm no external dependencies as a personal exercise. The task is to implement the least squares algorithm. From my reading I have learned about SVD, singular values, and Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse.

I have found an algorithm by Golub and Reinsch which calculates the reduced SVD (http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/References/Golub+Reinsch-NM-1970.pdf):

$A = \hat U \hat \Sigma V^*$

I also read that for:

$Ax = b$

$x = (A'A)^{-1}A'b$

If there is no solution (due to small error), A is not invertible, so Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse is used.

$A^+=(A'A)^{-1}A'$
and
$A^+=V\Sigma^+U^*$

My question is how do I expand $\hat U$ to be a full m x m matrix (given that A is m x n)?

Additionally I was wondering how error for each part of least squares is calculated.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but if you just want to convert a matrix in reduced SVD to full SVD form, just add zero rows to the bottom of the diagonal $\Sigma$ matrix, and append any orthogonal columns to $U$ so that it remains orthogonal. What do you mean by "error for each part of least squares"?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by orthogonal columns to $U$? I do realize that I can just add 0's to $\sigma$ however. For error I am reading a book pdf which states that the variance of b can be calculated with $ \sigma^2 * (X^'X)^{-1}$ . How is $\sigma$ calculated?

Comment: You can use Gram-Schmidt to find the remaining vectors and obtain an orthonormal basis.

Comment: If you're asking about least squares, please edit the question to show your thought process. As @RodrigodeAzevedo says, to expand to full SVD, simply take the $m$ existing columns and use Gram-Schmidt to find another $n-m$ orthogonal vectors.